# how to create AVAudioPCMBuffer from NSData

Tags: ios, avaudioengine, avaudiopcmbuffer

I receive mp3 from stream and convert pcm data. I try to use AVAudioEngine but can not create AVAudioPCMBuffer without file.

```
- (void)playAudio:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.runAudioThread = YES;
    dispatch_queue_t globalDispatchDefaultQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

    [_player play];

    dispatch_async(globalDispatchDefaultQueue, ^{
        while (_runAudioThread) {
            if (_rawDataArray.count > BUFFER_COUNT) {
                NSMutableData *rawData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
                NSArray *rawDataArray = _rawDataArray.copy;

                @synchronized(_rawDataArray) {
                    [self.rawDataArray removeAllObjects];
                }

                for (AudioPacketInfo *audioPacketInfo in rawDataArray) {
                    [rawData appendData:audioPacketInfo.data];
                }

                NSData *mp3Data = [AudioUtil makeMP3Data:rawData];
                if (mp3Data) {
                    NSData *pcmData = [AudioUtil convertToPCMWithData:mp3Data];
                    if (pcmData.length > 0) {
                        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                        NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
                        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/temp.mp3"];
                        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:mp3Data attributes:nil];

                        AVAudioFile *audioFile = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] error:nil];
                        AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:audioFile.processingFormat frameCapacity:(AVAudioFrameCount)audioFile.length];

                        [audioFile readIntoBuffer:buffer error:nil];
                        [_player scheduleBuffer:buffer completionHandler:nil];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

how would i do that?

[Convert mp3 to pcm](https://gist.github.com/bonggil-jeon/1d8c0ed11e7ee5ce843b)

Comment: what errors do you get? we need a lot more information, please post as much information as you can, and post your in code instead of linking to it.

Comment: @Clayton update my question.

Comment: What errors do you get, please be more specific or clear? what specifically does not work.

Comment: I play mp3 or pcm data without create file.

Comment: @Clayton I try to play using Audio Queue Service. Thanks for your advice.